# C - Pass By Value and Pass By Reference Inconsistency

Tags: c, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

When using pass by reference in C, sometimes the address passed to the called function changes:

```
void mainFunction()
{
  BYTE aAddress[10];
  readFunction(aAddress); // Address of aAddress: 0x111111
}

void readFunction(BYTE *pAddress) // Address of pAddress: 0x222222
{
  ...
}
```

Another issue I encountered, when using pass by value, the value received by the called function differs from what is passed to it.

```
void mainFunction()
{
  readFunction(0x20); // Passed value: 0x20
}

void readFunction(BYTE uValue) // Received value: 0x00
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: You *do* declare the functions before calling them? I.e. you have a prototype of `readFunction` before calling it in `mainFunction`?

Comment: Do you have prototypes for the function defined before the spot where the function is called?  If not try moving the function definition above the spot where it is called.  If that fixes it then the reason it doesn't work is because the compiler is assuming something about the function - and assuming it incorrectly.

Comment: Strictly speaking is no 'pass-by-reference' in C. How do you output the addresses? `pAddress` is a pointer that should point to the same location as `aAddress` when `readFunction` is called with `aAddress`.

Comment: First, C only passes by value, never by reference ... passing a pointer by value is passing by value. Second, post code that demonstrates your (highly implausible) claim, as you're probably making some other mistake. (General hint for beginners: 99.9% of the time it's your fault, not the tool's fault.) Finally, compile with warnings enabled ... your examples have prototype errors.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I declare the functions at the header files but still I got "implicit declaration" warning.

Comment: Are you declaring the functions *correctly*, i.e. the exact same way as they are defined? And you *do* include the header file in the source where you call the functions?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah the called function is located from other file

Comment: You should probably have done it sooner, but now is a good time to make a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that shows your problem. The pseudo-code in your question is not enough to explain either whats wrong, or how to solve your problem.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried declaring the function on the file where the function is called and it worked fine, do you think there's something wrong with my header file?

Comment: It sure seems like that.

Answer (score 2):

It all depends: How did you print the addresses? If you get the address of the variable, then *of course* they will be different. The value the pointers point to, however, will be the same::

```
int main ( void )
{
    char some_array[100];
    printf("array holds: %p\n", (void*) some_array);//same
    printf("Address in main: %p\n", (void*) &some_array[0]);//same
    pass_arr(some_array);
    return 0;
}
void pass_arr(char *arr)
{
    printf("Address of pointer VAR: %p\n", (void *) &arr);//PRINTS DIFFERENT ADDRESS
    printf("Pointer address: %p\n", (void *) arr);//same
    printf("points to: %p\n", (void *) &(*arr));//same
}
```

[check this codepad](http://codepad.org/NpySSNxu)
You probably failed to print the address of a variable correctly, the *only* right way is to use the `%p` placeholder, and to *cast the address to `void *`*. This is down to the fact that the way addresses are printed out is implementation dependent.

---

That said, you mention *"pass by reference"*. C doesn't pass by reference, it doesn't have references in the C++ sense. But in order for a function to alter the value of something else, you ought to pass a pointer to a pointer:

```
struct some_str
{
    int mem1;
    size_t mem2;
};
int main ( void )
{
    struct some_str *foo = malloc(sizeof *foo);
    set_value(&foo);
    free(foo);
    return 0;
}
void set_value(struct some_str **change)
{//pointer to pointer
    static int change_count = 0;
    (*change)->mem1 = 123;
    (*change)->mem2 = ++change_count;//for example
}
```

C *always* passes by value, in case of a pointer, that value is a memory address, in case of a primitive type (`int`, `char`, `long`...), it's not the *variable* but the *value* you're passing, if you pass a pointer to the variable (`&my_int`), you're not passing the variable, but its address in memory. Those are the only 2 options you have to choose from.

For more on the subject (arrays vs pointers, and why arrays decay into pointers in most cases [you may find this link useful](http://www.lysator.liu.se/c/c-faq/c-2.html))

Comment: One thing I would add is that C only has pass by value ... passing a pointer is a form of that; pass by reference is different.

Comment: @JimBalter: Added that to my answer, too. PS: perhaps change your comment to _"99% of times it's your fault, and the only tool in the operation is you"_ :)

Comment: I would use something other than an array for the pointer to pointer example ... my_array isn't a pointer, you can't change its value, and my_array and &my_array are numerically equal (but have different sizeof).

Comment: @JimBalter: there's also pass-by-text, but we don't talk about that =)

Comment: @JimBalter: Changed it to a heap-allocated struct, and as for pass by text, I'll add a link that does touch on that =)

Comment: Thank you for all your responses, I'll take note of them. I just started coding using C language for standalone devices with limited stack size and I'm still a little bit confused in using pointers. But my second concern still bothers me, how did it happen.

Comment: @user3243346: That is impossible to say, given the code you've posted here. _how are you printing the mem-addresses?_ that's the question

Comment: How can I get the address of the direct value passed? (readFunction(0x20); 0x20 as the value itself)

Comment: I think there's something wrong with my header file, when I tried to declare the function in the C file where it is called, it worked fine.

Comment: @user3243346: Perhaps, but given that you aren't showing any code, I can't tell...

Comment: @user3243346 "How can I get the address of the direct value passed?" -- This question makes no sense; it seems to be asking how to get the address of a literal such as 0x20. For at least the 5th time: Post real code that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: @user3243346: _"How can I get the address of the direct value passed"_. Not sure what you mean, but I take it you're asking if there is any way of knowing where the value that was passed is stored in memory in associated with the calling function. Well, that'd be _A pointer_, which passes the memory address. Anything else is just absurd. If you think that `0x20` value is stored only once, your question is like asking me where the word _"ni"_ is stored... it isn't stored in just one place. Any copy of Monty Python and the holy Grail contains about 100 _"Ni"_'s

Answer (score 1):

> When using pass by reference in C, sometimes the address passed to the called function changes

--> NO. Look at this code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void readFunction (int *pAddress) 
{
    printf("Address of pAddress: %p\n", &pAddress);
    printf("Content of pAddress: %p\n", pAddress);
}

void main()
{
    int a[10];
    printf("Address of a: %p\n", &a);
    readFunction(a);
}
```

when execute it, you will get something as:

```
Address of a: 0xbfb94948
Address of pAddress: 0xbfb94930
Content of pAddress: 0xbfb94948
```

The `pAddress` is located in another place but it still points to the address of `a`. And this is the primitive of pass by reference

Comment: Cast your pointers, and explain _"this is the primitive of pass by reference"_

Comment: The C language does not support "pass by reference". At all. The closest you can get is the passing of a _pointer_ by _value_. There are people who insist that this constitutes "pass by reference", but this is not correct.

Comment: When passing a pointer to `printf()` to be printed using the `%p` conversion, the pointer must always be cast to `(void *)`.